# How to resolve process.on test TypeScript Mocha Testing using Sinon Spy?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, spy

I want to test the warning process for a Typescript project. The code that I'm trying to test is the following:

```
process.on('warning', (warning) => {
    LoggingService.info('Warning, Message: ' + warning.message + ' Stack: ' + warning.stack, 'warning');
});
```

I'm using `sinnon.spy` to perform the test as follows:

```
it('Check warning process', (done) => {
        const spy = sinon.spy(LoggingService, 'info');
        process.on('uncaughtException', () => {
            sinon.assert.calledWith(spy, "warning")
            done()
        })
        process.emit('warning')
    })
```

I have the following error with the my test case above:

```
Argument of type '"warning"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"disconnect"'.
```

How am I able to resolve this error, since the warning process is defined in the code I'm trying to test?
Thanks very much, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sinon.stub` to stub `process.on` method and its implementation.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
process.on('warning', (warning) => {
  console.info('Warning, Message: ' + warning.message + ' Stack: ' + warning.stack, 'warning');
});
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('63119397', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should print warning message', () => {
    const warning = {
      message: 'go',
      stack: 'go:13',
    };
    sinon.stub(process, 'on').callsFake((event, callback) => {
      callback(warning);
    });
    const infoSpy = sinon.spy(console, 'info');
    require('./');
    sinon.assert.calledWith(process.on, 'warning', sinon.match.func);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(infoSpy, 'Warning, Message: go Stack: go:13', 'warning');
  });
});
```

unit test result with 100% coverage report:

```sh
  63119397
Warning, Message: go Stack: go:13 warning
    ✓ should print warning message (796ms)


  1 passing (808ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the purpose of `require('./');` before the `sinon.assert`s